# Insert new line with text after n lines and 3 lines at beginning from other file - Windows

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, sqlcmd

Could you please help find a **Windows** solution that can solve the below needs?

Currently I do this manually in Notepad++ with regular expression, but this routine will be used by several persons and an automatic way will be better.

I have a huge text file containing insert statements which will be loaded in SQL Server. 
What I'm trying to do is:
**1** - insert BEGIN TRANSACTION; at the beginning of the file 
**2** - insert COMMIT TRANSACTION; at the END of the file 
**3** - insert 3 new lines with text after every 1000 lines: 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;    
        GO
        BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
**4** - Copy the first 3 line from another file to current file

This thing will happen in **dynamic paths**.

Here is an example for a file with 5000 lines:

**Input**

Line_No Text
1             insert into... 
500           insert into... 
1000          insert into... 
1001          insert into... 
2000          insert into... 
2001          insert into... 
5000          insert into...

**Desired output**

Line_No Text
1st  line with text from other file in same path 
2nd  line with text from other file in same path 
3rd  line with text from other file in same path 
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
1             insert into... 
500           insert into... 
1000          insert into... 
1001          COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
1002          GO 
1003          BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
1004          insert into... 
2000          insert into... 
2001          COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
2002          GO 
2003          BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
2004          insert into... 
5000          insert into... 
5001          COMMIT TRANSACTION;   

Thank you so much! :)

UPDATE:
Here is the solution for doing this task using the solution @mjolinor has provided:

```
$cd = Get-Location
$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
$newfile = "$cd\newfile.sql"
$oldfile = "$cd\oldfile.sql"
$string = Get-Content $cd\otherfile.txt

$header = @"
:out $PSScriptRoot\log.txt
USE $string
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
"@

$insert = @'
COMMIT TRANSACTION; 
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
'@

$header | Set-Content $newfile
 Get-Content $oldfile -ReadCount 1000 |
   ForEach-Object { $_,$insert | Add-Content $newfile -Force}
 'COMMIT TRANSACTION;' | Add-Content $newfile
```

Thank you @mjolinor :-) !

Comment: This is not a question but a task request. Please try it on your own, share your efforts and describe precisely where you are stuck, including what your code is supposed to do and what it actually does.

Comment: You say you can already do this with regex... In PowerShell you can use `$text -replace 'regexpattern', 'newvalue'` to replace using regex. Personally I would use some type of loop and a counter.

Comment: It is also not clear what exactly you mean by "dynamic paths" neither what file to pick in step 4 (copy the first 3 line from another file to current file)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested extensively, but I thing this should work:

```
$newfile = 'c:\somedir\newfilename.txt'
$oldfile = 'c:\somedir\oldfilename.txt'
$otherfile = 'c:\somedir\someotherfilename.txt'

$insert = @'
COMMIT TRANSACTION; 
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
'@

'BEGIN TRANSACTION' | Set-Content $newfile
 Get-Content $oldfile -ReadCount 1000 |
   ForEach-Object { $_,$insert | Add-Content $newfile }
 Get-Content $otherfile -Head 3 | Add-Content $newfile
```

Comment: Thank you very much mjolinor. Your solution work very well!